# prettier is not picking up .svelte files without specifying them explicitly

Tags: svelte, prettier

I've created a svelte project and wanted to use prettier. I have prettier svelte plugin.

```
pnpm exec prettier --write .
```

will only pick up js and html files.

```
pnpm exec prettier --write .src/routes/+page.svelte
```

or

```
pnpm exec prettier --write . **.svelte
```

will work correctly and pick up all the files.

isn't the expected behavior or prettier to pick up svelte files too? Why doesn't it pick them up?

Comment: You may need to install the Svelte Prettier plug-in of you haven't already. https://github.com/sveltejs/prettier-plugin-svelte

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get prettier to format my vscode by going to the `.vscode` folder at project root (create one if you dont have it) and adding a settings.json file with:

```
{
    "[svelte]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "svelte.svelte-vscode"
    }
}
```

I discovered this while looking at the docs for [this plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=svelte.svelte-vscode) which I installed.

Comment: Issue is not related to vscode configuration at all. Only CLI tools and and npm scripts. I am experiencing the same issue using vim as a code editor.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in Prettier, I've had this on Prettier version `3.0.0`.

The workaround is to explicitly provide the `--plugin` option like this:

```
pnpm exec prettier --plugin 'prettier-plugin-svelte' --write .
```

Or simply upgrade your Prettier to latest version. I can confirm `3.2.5` works correctly.